# Product adding to cart and remove count is missing, while remove items in opencart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I am using below script for adding products to cart and remove , where i m displaying count how many added and after remove how many left...in my script when i am removing count is not showing and after refreshing the page count is showing where i am missed logic...

```
// Cart add remove functions
var cart = {
    'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('reset');
            },          
            success: function(json) {
                $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

                if (json['redirect']) {
                    location = json['redirect'];
                }

                if (json['success']) {
                    $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

                    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
                    }, 100);

                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

                    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                }
            }
        });
    },
    'update': function(key, quantity) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'key=' + key + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('reset');
            },          
            success: function(json) {
                if( json['total']){
                    var total= json['total'];
                }
                else{
                    var total="";
                }
                // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
                }, 100);

                if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                    location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
                } else {
                    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                }
            }
        });
    },
    'remove': function(key) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'key=' + key,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('reset');
            },          
            success: function(json) {
                // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
                if( json['total']){
                    var total= json['total'];
                }
                else{
                    var total="";
                }
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#cart > button').html('<i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>Cart<span id="cart-total">' + total + '</span>');
                }, 100);

                if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                    location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
                } else {
                    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify your code in "remove" section:
Change below:

```
 setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#cart > button').html('<i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>Cart<span id="cart-total">' + total + '</span>');
                }, 100);
```

To Below:

```
setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
                }, 100);
```